# get all child views inside linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linearlayout,I have dynamically created child views, which contains edittext,checkbox,spinner,radio button. I am getting value of all edittext but I dont know how will I get values of all checked checkbox and selected item of radio button and spinner dynamically,please help me,below is my code to get all child views of linearlayout.

```
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View newView = ll.getChildAt(i);
                    if (newView instanceof EditText) {
                        EditText et = (EditText) newView;
                        //validate your EditText here
                        stringBuilder.append("EditText: " + et.getText());
                        stringBuilder.append("/n");
                    } else if (newView instanceof RadioButton) {
                        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) newView; 

//need to get value of selected radtio button
                    } 
                    else if (newView instanceof Spinner) {
                        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) newView;
                        String str = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        stringBuilder.append("Spinner: " + str.toString());
                        stringBuilder.append("/n")

//here i am able to get value of spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); but unable to append in stringBuilder.

                    } else if (newView instanceof CheckBox) {
                        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) newView;

//need to get value of all selected checkbox 

                      }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: `chk.isChecked()`

Comment: You could store references to the views when you create them. Then you don't need this code at all.

Answer (score 0):

try this for get value of selected RadioButton:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    {
        radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```